# unable to install ubuntu 22.04 on my pc

Tags: boot, system-installation

My PC specs:
graphics: nvidia 3060
motherboard : B550M DS3H
processor: AMD Ryzen 5600x

Things I've tried

1. I've tried installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, using the first option. But after a minute it's stuck on the motherboard's manufacturer logo forever.
2. I've selected the safe graphics; it did install but now it's stuck on a message saying
   `/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 175814/30498816 files ...`
3. I've changed the grub setting, and added `nomodeset`. But that didn't work to. followed the article from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting)

Comment: Did you check for any B550M firmware updates?  Sometimes those fix many problems.

Comment: yes i did, but there are no updates